# Custom exception not being handled

Tags: error-handling

The custom exception looks like this:

```
public class ExceptionA extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public ExceptionA() {
        super();
    }
    public ExceptionA(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

The implementation looks something like this:

```
public void remove(E elem) {
       if(contains(elem)) {
         for(int i = 0; i< data.length;i++) {
             if(data[i]== elem) {
                 data[i] = null;
                 size --;
                
                 break;
                 }
             
                }
             
             }else {
                 throw new ExceptionA(message);
             }
         }
```

The problem I'm having isn't really in the exception being thrown, it's in the fact that my catch block isn't handling it.

```
try {
            bag.remove(elem);
        } catch (ExceptionA ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
```

I'm not sure if anything of what I'm doing is wrong any tips would be appreciated